# What is the difference between onClick="javascript: function('value')'" and onClick="function('value');"?

Tags: javascript, function, function-calls

What is the difference between the following?

1. `onClick="javascript: function('value');"`
2. `onClick="function('value');"`

When do I use the `javascript:` before the function call, and why?

Can I call the function without using `javascript:` prefix?

Please help me understand the difference.

Comment: [Avoid onclick attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: the `javascript:` prefix is only necessary in `href`, which wouldn't normally contain JS code.

Comment: why the `javascript` is needed in the `href`? any help on this please explain me it will very helpful to me to understood the diffrence@Spudley

Comment: Note that the answer to this applies to _any_ JavaScript in an inline event handler, not just a function call. E.g., you can say `onclick="return false;"` rather than `onclick="javascript:return false;"`.

Comment: it means when i have to use the incline code at that time i have to use the `javascript:`. am i right?? @nnnnnn

Comment: No. You just don't ever need `javascript:` in an inline event handler.

Comment: please explain it me in the answer so i can understood it in right way.@nnnnnn

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In an element's inline event handler, like `onclick`, `onchange`, `onsubmit`, etc., you do *not* need the `javascript:` prefix - the reason you often see it is because people confuse it with the `href` syntax that I explain below. It doesn't cause an error - I believe it is interpreted as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) - but it is unnecessary.

It doesn't matter whether you want to call a function or run a "simple" JS statement, either way don't include `javascript:` - that is, all three of these are valid:

```
onclick="doSomething('some val');"
onclick="return false;"
onclick="doSomething(); doSomethingElse(); return false;"
```

**If you are using inline event attributes don't use the `javascript:` prefix.**

(I say "*if* you are using inline event attributes" because this practice is really outdated: it is better to assign the event handlers using JS in a script block.)

You only need the `javascript:` prefix when you want to run JavaScript from an `<a>` element's `href` attribute like this:

```
<a href="javascript: someFunc();">Whatever</a>
```

That is because the browser normally expects the `href` to contain a URI, so the `javascript:` prefix tells it to expect JS code instead. However, I don't recommending doing that because the page won't work for people who have JS disabled. Better to include an `href` that directs the user to a page telling them to enable JS, and include an `onclick` to do the JS functionality:

```
<a href="/enableJS.html" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Whatever</a>
```

That way the link does something useful for users whether they have JS enabled or not. The `return false` at the end of the click handler prevents the default behaviour for a click (which would be to navigate to the specified URL).

Answer (score 7):

The first one has a completely redundant [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

> When should i have to use the "javascript:" before the function call and what is the reason of use it?

Never. (Well, almost. You do use it in `javascript:` scheme URIs, but you should only use those if you are writing a bookmarklet, and they wouldn't appear in an `onclick` attribute).

(`javascript:` URIs are where the [cargo-cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) practice of prefixing `onclick` attribute values with a label came from.)

> can i call the function without using "javascript:"??

Yes.